How to detect if a URL has changed in TMS WEB Core?
I have a TMS WEB Core application with code all over the place that changes the URL via the window.history.pushState function.
Is there a way I can detect when the URL has changed?
Let's say for instance my URL is "www.example.com/index.html?page=hello" and then something in the code changes it to "www.example.com/index.html?page=bye".
How can I detect that the URL has changed from my Delphi code? I don't necessarily need to know what has changed in the URL, I just need to know that the URL has been changed.
Edit: I've done some testing and TWebForm.OnHashChange isn't what I need as that only checks hashes, but it is useful still. I did some testing in vanilla JavaScript and it seems like onPopState is what I might need, but I'm not sure how to do this in Delphi as it's not exposed like OnHashChange. It appears like I need a combination of things actually, but onPopState is the missing piece that I think I need.
The Navigation_API also seems promising, but I haven't tested that one yet as it doesn't have full support in all browsers as of June 2024.

The Delphi context doesn't matter - read the A's in How to get notified about changes of the history via history.pushState? to see that there's no bullet proof way. Which means you're experiencing a technical dept now where calling your own function (which in turn calls .pushState()) would have been the better choice to intercept all those calls. Your "Delphi code" is easily reachable the same way you did it a couple of times before: call a function.

Have you tried to use TWebForm.OnHashChange ?

@JohnEasley That's for when the anchor in a URI changes, not one of its parameters. Hence the name "hash": because of the anchor sign.

@AmigoJack Ahh, it works for me because I host all other forms besides my main form (which contains all my navigation) in a TWebPanel contained on my main form.
